# if condition is met replace all but not if another condition is met dplyr in R

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, replace, conditional-statements

I am trying to replace all values in `nat_locx` with the value from the first row in `LOCX` and replace all the `distance` values with 0 if my first condition is met one or more times for `id` (my `group_by()` variable), but NOT if my second condition is met one or more times for `id`.

Here is an example of my data:

```
  id         DATE       nat_locx  LOCX distance loc_age  condition
 <fct>       <date>        <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>  <lgl>
 6553        2004-06-27     13.5   2    487.90       26  TRUE
 6553        2004-07-14     13.5  13.5    0          43  FALSE
 6553        2004-07-15     13.5  12.5   30          44  FALSE  
 10160       2005-07-01      4.5    12 229.45588     36  TRUE          
 10160       2005-07-05      4.5    11 200.12496     40  TRUE     
 10160       2005-07-06      4.5    11 200.12496     41  TRUE
```

The way I have tried to do this is like so:

```
df<-df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(condition = case_when(     
    loc_age >= 25 & loc_age < 40 & distance > 30 ~ TRUE, 
    loc_age>=40 & loc_age<50 & distance>60 ~ TRUE,
    TRUE ~ FALSE)) %>%  
mutate(nat_locx=if(condition=="TRUE") {
        first(LOCX) & distance==0.00
        } else {
        nat_locx})
```

The first `mutate()` results in a new column with `TRUE` and `FALSE` values. If there is even one instance of `FALSE`, then the `if` `else` statement I write afterwards should not proceed.

In this example, this would mean that for `id==6553` the loop should not change anything. But, because `condition==TRUE` for every row for `id==10160` then the `if` `else` should proceed.

Ideally, I'd like this output:

```
  id         DATE       nat_locx  LOCX distance loc_age  condition
 <fct>       <date>        <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>  <lgl>
 6553        2004-06-27     13.5   2    487.90       26  TRUE
 6553        2004-07-14     13.5  13.5    0          43  FALSE
 6553        2004-07-15     13.5  12.5   30          44  FALSE  
 10160       2005-07-01      12    12     0          36  TRUE          
 10160       2005-07-05      12    11     0          40  TRUE     
 10160       2005-07-06      12    11     0          41  TRUE
```

A `dplyr` solution is preferred.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but perhaps you may want `nat_locx=if(all(condition=="TRUE"))...`? (or just `if(all(condition))`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Ben mentioned, we can include `all` so that the changes are only applied to groups that have all `TRUE`. We can use this for both `nat_locx` and for the `distance` columns.

```
library(tidyverse)


df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(
    condition = case_when(
      loc_age >= 25 & loc_age < 40 & distance > 30 ~ TRUE,
      loc_age >= 40 & loc_age < 50 & distance > 60 ~ TRUE,
      TRUE ~ FALSE
    )
  ) %>%
  mutate(nat_locx = if (all(condition)) first(LOCX) else nat_locx,
         distance = if (all(condition)) 0 else distance)
```

**Output**

```
     id DATE       nat_locx  LOCX distance loc_age condition
  <int> <chr>         <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>   <int> <lgl>    
1  6553 2004-06-27     13.5   2       488.      26 TRUE     
2  6553 2004-07-14     13.5  13.5       0       43 FALSE    
3  6553 2004-07-15     13.5  12.5      30       44 FALSE    
4 10160 2005-07-01     12    12         0       36 TRUE     
5 10160 2005-07-05     12    11         0       40 TRUE     
6 10160 2005-07-06     12    11         0       41 TRUE
```